# Why is my child div overflowing outside of the parent div?

Tags: html, css

I have always had this problem and I avoid floating div's because of this problem. The code seems to work but when you inspect the code in Google's developer tools it shows that the Main div is 0px tall. the problem I have with this is what if I want the Main div to have an image or a color. The solution I found to getting this to work is applying a float to every div so Main would also get a float but floating the Main div will break the centering of the main container. Does anyone know of a way to fix the two divs going outside of the main div?

```css
.float-left {
  float: left;
}

.float-right {
  float: right;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  background-color: darkgray;
}

.div1 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}

.div2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: darkblue;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/reset200802.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<main>
  <div class="div1 float-left"></div>
  <div class="div2 float-right"></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Floating the child divs remove them from the flow of the document, so the main element collapses to zero height

Comment: You need to clear the floats

Comment: I would recommend not using floats, flex and grid are newer, widely supported and avoid these types of issues.